Update record on same table which is using in FROM clause
I am trying to update the record on table which is using in FROM clause. When I execute it, it taking more time to execute (nearly 5 hrs).
Below are the details attached.
Update statement
UPDATE schema_name.tbl_bllng upd
SET
rsv_clm = Mc.c_fullform
, counter = tbll.counter + 1
 
FROM
    schema_name.tbl_bllng tbll
    INNER JOIN schema_name.tbl_ihdr ihdr
    ON(
    ihdr.b_id = tbll.b_id
    AND ihdr.Icnt = 0
    AND ihdr.id = 1
    AND ihdr.active_flg = False)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN public.schema_name2.master_table Mc
    ON(
    ihdr.rsv_clm IS NOT NULL
    AND Mc.ic_id = ihdr.rsv_clm
    AND Mc.id = 1
    AND Mc.cd = 1
    AND Mc.active_flg = False)
    WHERE
    tbll.tseq_id = upd.tseq_id
    AND tbll.id = 1
    AND tbll.active_flg = False;

QUERY PLAN
Update on tbl_bllng upd  (cost=1.14..932050009.01 rows=53247247974 width=8053)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.14..932050009.01 rows=53247247974 width=8053)
        Merge Cond: ((tbll.b_id)::text = (ihdr.b_id)::text)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..108174.20 rows=171730 width=7628)
              ->  Index Scan using idx_bllng_id on tbl_bllng tbll  (cost=0.29..13970.46 rows=171730 width=23)
                    Index Cond: ((id = 1) AND (active_flg = false))
              ->  Index Scan using bllng_pkc on tbl_bllng upd  (cost=0.42..0.55 rows=1 width=7613)
                    Index Cond: (tseq_id = tbll.tseq_id)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.43..117666.47 rows=1240212 width=95)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..114565.94 rows=1240212 width=95)
                    Join Filter: ((ihdr.rsv_clm IS NOT NULL) AND ((Mc.ic_id)::text = (ihdr.rsv_clm)::text))
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_tbl_bll on tbl_ihdr ihdr  (cost=0.43..95961.70 rows=1240212 width=429)
                          Index Cond: ((Icnt = 0) AND (id = 1) AND (active_flg = false))
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=162)
                          ->  Seq Scan on "schema_name2.master_table" Mc  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=162)
                                Filter: ((NOT active_flg) AND (id = 1) AND (cd = 1))

Table names and Record counts
schema_name2.master_table this table 4 record only
schema_name.tbl_bllng - 171010
schema_name.tbl_ihdr -1240212

Table datatype:
tbl_ihdr
b_id-----(string)
Icnt---integer
rsv_clm --> string
id-----int
active_flg---Boolean

tbl_bllng
b_id--------> string
tseq_id  -- Int
id---int
active_flg---boolean

I am new to query tuning, Please help on this to resolve this issue.

Seems, your inner join gets rows=53247247974. Very close to the cartesian join. Check join conditions.

You accidentally did a self-join of schema_name.tbl_bllng with itself. It's already implicitly joined to as the update target, so you don't need to list it again as the update source. See the UPDATE..FROM documentation:

Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_item).

Move the join conditions specifying how the target correlates to the first source down to the where section. You can leave the other join as it is:
UPDATE schema_name.tbl_bllng upd
SET
rsv_clm = Mc.c_fullform
, counter = upd.counter + 1
FROM schema_name.tbl_ihdr ihdr
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.schema_name2.master_table Mc
ON( ihdr.rsv_clm IS NOT NULL
    AND Mc.ic_id = ihdr.rsv_clm
    AND Mc.id = 1
    AND Mc.cd = 1
    AND Mc.active_flg = False
    --these were moved from the old join, filtering the first source:
    AND ihdr.Icnt = 0
    AND ihdr.id = 1
    AND ihdr.active_flg = False )
--this specifies how update target joins to the first source:
WHERE ihdr.b_id = upd.b_id 
--these narrow down what to update in the traget:
AND upd.tseq_id = upd.tseq_id
AND upd.id = 1
AND upd.active_flg = False;

Alternatively, you could keep the self-join, but you need to make it a qualified join. Otherwise every row of your update target will join to any other row, multiplying everything, before being filtered a bit by your where and join conditions.
UPDATE schema_name.tbl_bllng upd
SET
rsv_clm = Mc.c_fullform
, counter = tbll.counter + 1
FROM
    schema_name.tbl_bllng tbll
INNER JOIN schema_name.tbl_ihdr ihdr
    ON(
    ihdr.b_id = tbll.b_id
    AND upd.ctid=tbll.ctid --this will make the self-join qualified 1:1
    AND ihdr.Icnt = 0
    AND ihdr.id = 1
    AND ihdr.active_flg = False)
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.schema_name2.master_table Mc
    ON(
    ihdr.rsv_clm IS NOT NULL
    AND Mc.ic_id = ihdr.rsv_clm
    AND Mc.id = 1
    AND Mc.cd = 1
    AND Mc.active_flg = False)
WHERE
    tbll.tseq_id = upd.tseq_id
    AND upd.ctid=tbll.ctid --you can sneak it in here instead
    AND tbll.id = 1
    AND tbll.active_flg = False;

ctid is a unique system column in every table, but you can also use a primary key.
